# "Unable to connect" error with apt-get: possible proxy?

Tags: 12.04, apt, sudo

I've been having an issue with 'sudo apt-get update' for several days now. I've tried every proposed solution I could find but to no avail.  Here is the output to 'apt-get update'.

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en_US
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try Changing your mirror via Software sources, check your Internet Connection also.

Comment: I've tried many mirrors, the result is always the same. I don't have any connection issues, I am directly connected to my building's internet service and there does not appear to be a proxy.

Comment: try `ping 69.163.233.85` and `ping archive.ubuntu.com` in a terminal

Answer (score 4):

The key is this part:

```
Unable to connect to 69.163.233.85:80
```

- That IP address does not correspond to *us.archive.ubuntu.com*
- In fact, it belongs to the [hosting company DreamHost!](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-69-163-128-0-1)
- So this is most likely a proxy, or a manual IP mapping via `/etc/hosts` that was set but is no longer working. Please pastebin the output of `apt-config dump` and we can try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it seemed that a global proxy setting was somehow still active for `apt`, while not for the rest of the system. Re-applying not using a proxy via the Network Settings fixed the problem for me.