# Connection failure occurs while updating Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, apt

I am unable to do an update operation using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The connection goes to a server with IP 10.30.10.45 and it gets timed out, in spite of being connected to the internet. Please suggest a solution.

The following occurs:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
0% [Connecting to 10.30.10.45 (10.30.10.45)] [Connecting to 10.30.10.45 (10.30.
```

I recently tried to install Zotero Libreoffice plugin, which resulted in a failure. Could it be related to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to connect" error with apt-get: possible proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181401/unable-to-connect-error-with-apt-get-possible-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It was because of a proxy that was set for getting apt updates. I had once set it while using an office WiFi. So, I deleted the file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy` and everything worked as normal.