# Gateway timeout when running apt-get update

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, lts

When I run `apt-get update` on my ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I get the following error messages

```
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/communitheme/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
Err:3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
Err:5 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
Err:6 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
W: Failed to fetch http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/communitheme/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 135.245.192.7 8000]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong and I haven't found a solution on google yet. Is this an error on my part? I don't remember changing anything on my install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>This is not obvious what is your network config. I do not have enough reputation score to ask more info in comment, sorry</sub>

Looks similar to ["Unable to connect" error with apt-get: possible proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181401/unable-to-connect-error-with-apt-get-possible-proxy?rq=1)

I believe 135.245.192.7:8000 is the proxy server and port.
"Gateway timeout" tells us the proxy is busy.
Please try some other time.

Or do you have a chance to change the proxy?

Please compare the proxy setting in browser and current APT settings, probably in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf`. As per your questions you have access to internet via browser.

Here are references for the apt proxy

- [https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-apt-for-ubuntu-18-04/](http://How%20to%20Set%20the%20Proxy%20for%20APT%20on%20Ubuntu%2018.04)

  > ````
  > Acquire {
  >   http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
  >   https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy.server:port/";
  > }```
  > ````
- [apt.conf "Acquire::http:Proxy "proxyserver:port" seems not to be used (Ubuntu 13.04 under Virtual Box on Win7)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349702/apt-conf-acquirehttpproxy-proxyserverport-seems-not-to-be-used-ubuntu-13)

Comment: Indeed, apparently I had an outdated proxy config. Thanks!